# How to merge two gz files into new outputfile with specific name

Tags: gzip, merge

I have 96 *fastqc.gz raw read files from 24 samples. Each sample was sequenced on two lanees for each pair.

I would like to merge reads for each pair from both lanes into one output file with same name identifier from sample file name (2271_merged_R1_001.fastq.gz).

```
File names are in this order:
22[71-94]*R[1-2]_001.fastq.gz;

**2271**_ID890_1_S1_L001_**R1_001.fastq.gz**
**2271**_ID890_1_S1_L002_**R1_001.fastq.gz**

**2271**_ID890_1_S1_L001_**R2_001.fastq.gz**
**2271**_ID890_1_S1_L002_**R2_001.fastq.gz**
```

I tried the following short script but only two output files are being generated (first and the last).

FOR R1 files

```
  for rf in 22[71-94]*R1_001.fastq.gz; do zcat $rf > 22"${71-94}"_merged_R1_001.fastq.gz ; done
```

FOR R2 files

```
for rf in 22[71-94]*R2_001.fastq.gz; do zcat $rf > 22"${71-94}"_merged_R2_001.fastq.gz ; done
```

My Questions are:
 1. Why only two output files are generated?
 2. The number of reads in the out put files are not the sum of the merged files from both lanes.
 3. Is there a nice way, I could do the merging of reads from both lanes for both (R1 and R2) in single step instead of running it two times for each read type.

What went wrong in the code? and how could I verify that the output files are completely merged?

Thanks

Comment: Are there literal asterisk characters in your file names, or were you trying to do bold formatting in the code block? Also, what are the filenames of your two output files?

Answer (score 1):

First, `22[71-94]*R1_001.fastq.gz` does not expand to what you think it expands to

This is effectively `22[1-9]*R1_001.fastq.gz` - in this, [71-94] is a character grouping where "7 OR 1 to 9 OR 4" simplifies to "1 to 9".

`22{71..94}*R1_001.fastq.gz` is most likely the expansion you were looking for, but your loop will perform `zcat` once for each file found, not concatenate things together. Effectively, every `R1` file sequentially gets `zcat`-ed into the same outfile, overwriting the previous writes.

I believe this is what you're actually looking for given an assumption(see below):

```
for num in {71..94}; do zcat 22"$num"*R1_{L001,L002}.fastq.gz > "22${num}_merged_R1_001.fastq" ; done
```

**Assumption:** You want the result to be decompressed, thus I removed the `.gz` from the resulting files (as pointed out by Patrick)
If this is not the case, simply change `zcat` to `cat` and append `.gz` to the resulting file again.

Comment: Your solution is `zcat`ing the files, so they're uncompressed, and then storing them in a file with the extension `.gz`. Either it should not be `.gz`, or you should recompress. Note however if your end result is compressed, there's no reason to `zcat` at all, just use `cat` and avoid the decompress/compression steps.

Comment: @Patrick True, I've removed the `.gz` extension from the resulting files, as that was simply duplicating what the intended filenames were in the OP's post.